# jquery show / hide elements with same starting

Tags: jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I have got thirty divs and thirty buttons. Each button hides previously opened div and opens different div. For example:

There is div called 'divnr4' oppened. I press button number 7 and divnr4 dissapears, but appears divnr7. How i could do this? I'm thinking about to use something like

```
$('#divnr').hide();
$('#divnr7').show();
```

but i'm not sure if it works and how to do this correctly.

Please help :)

Comment: So only one div is open at any time? Can you post some HTML?

Comment: now it looks like:
function showandhide(number) {
   $('div').hide();
   $('#klausimas'+number).show();
   $('#navigacija').show();
   $('#atsmenu').show();
   return false;
  }
for ($i=1;$i<31;$i++) {
echo '<div id="klausimas'.$i.'" name="klausimas'.$i.'">CONTENT</div>';
}
for ($i=1;$i<31;$i++) {
  echo '<button id="press" onClick="showandhide('.$i.'); return false;">'.$i.'</button>';
  }

Answer (score 5):

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $( "div[id^=divnr]" ).hide();
    $( "#divnr" + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) ).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9EbZL/)

Comment: i didn't get this line : $( "div[id^=divnr]" ).hide();
it closes all divs starting divnr ?

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas Exactly - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 1):

If only one div is open at a time, you can invoke some code to display the chosen div and hide the rest. [This link](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/) has a working example that will demonstrate what I mean.